# Accessing variables between visualforce page to controller classes

Tags: apex, visualforce, after-trigger

The following code is called from Opportunity trigger. So the flow is

1. From opportunity trigger call MyTwiMLController.processoutboundCall()
2. After the callout it calls the VF page "TwiMLPage"
3. Then it goes back to controller method getTwiml()

The challenge I am facing is that I am loosing the variables that I had set in the controller and inside of getTwiml() I cannot access any of the controller variables. What am I missing here?

Controller

```
    public class MyTwiMLController {

    public MyTwiMLController() {
        this.toContactList = toContactList;
    }
    Public String callerName{get;set;}
    String formattedtoNum;
    String accountName;
    public List<String>toContactList = new list<String>();

    public List<String> processoutboundCall(List<String> toPhNumberList){
        String toPhNumber = toPhNumberList.get(0);
        accountName    = toPhNumberList.get(2);
        formattedtoNum = toPhNumber.replaceAll('[^0-9]', '');


        Map<String,String> params = new Map<String,String> {
                'To'   => formattedtoNum,
                'From' => '+15628816679',
                'Url'  =>  'http://pk-silo.cs29.force.com/TwiMLPage'
        };
        findContact(accountName);
        DoCallout(params);

        return toContactList;
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    private static void DoCallout(Map<String, String> params){
          TwilioConfig__c tw = TwilioConfig__c.getInstance();
          String account = tw.AccountSid__c;
          String token   = tw.AuthToken__c;
          TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(account, token);
          TwilioCall call = client.getAccount().getCalls().create(params);
          system.debug('TwilioCAL LOG' + call);
    }

    public String findContact(String acntName){

        String website = [SELECT Website FROM Account WHERE Name=: acntName].Website;
        toContactList.add(website);
        return null;
    }

    public String getTwiml() {
        //here i am trying to access the list
        String temp = toContactList.get(0);
        String introMsg = 'Hello you will be connected with merchant for'+accountName+' who is looking for loan. ' +
                           'Please search for most recent Opportunity under'+accountName;
        TwilioTwiML.Response res = new TwilioTwiML.Response();
        res.append(new TwilioTwiML.Say(introMsg));
        res.append(new TwilioTwiML.Hangup());
        return res.toXML();
    }
}
```

Visualforce page

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<apex:page controller="MyTwiMLController" sideBar="false" showHeader="false" contentType="application/xml">
   {!twiml}
</apex:page>
```

Trigger

```
    if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        OpportunityContactRole contactRoleArray = [select Contact.Account.Name,Contact.MobilePhone,Contact.Name from OpportunityContactRole where OpportunityId = :opp.id AND Role='Primary Contact'];
        String toPhoneNum = contactRoleArray.Contact.MobilePhone;
        if(opp.Status__c == 'QW-RV' && toPhoneNum != null){
            List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
            toAddress.add(contactRoleArray.Contact.MobilePhone);
            toAddress.add(contactRoleArray.Contact.Name);
            toAddress.add(contactRoleArray.Contact.Account.Name);
            MyTwiMLController myTwiML = new MyTwiMLController();
            myTwiML.processoutboundCall(toAddress);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly is this Visualforce page involved in a trigger? I don't follow the sequence of functionality.

Comment: Yeah this post is confused and hence confusing. You should never assume there even is a UI in your trigger context.

Comment: trigger calls "processoutboundcall" method and in the url parameter in the outbound call "'http://pk-silo.cs29.force.com/TwiMLPage'" invokes the VF page.(This is part of Twilio Integration). After VF page is invoked it then call getTwiml method. "http://pk-silo.cs29.force.com/TwiMLPage" is a site page invoked from Twilio when we make HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger and an inbound load of a Visualforce page hosted in a Force.com Site do not share a transaction context or a view state. You cannot share data between them in controller instance variables because they do not share a controller instance.

URL parameters or some kind of persistent session store would need to be used to make data from the trigger invocation available to an inbound call. Twilio may be able to support you, but the current approach is non-workable.